# Javascript Google calender api not working

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

In my site i want to add events to google calender using javascript api.I changed the mail by mine.But i got error in fire bug.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
 google.load("gdata", "1");
 google.setOnLoadCallback(getMyFeed);
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myService;
 var feedUrl = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/galtech.staffs@gmail.com/private/full";
 function logMeIn() {
   scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/";
   var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
 }
 function setupMyService() {
   myService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1');
   logMeIn();
 }
 function getMyFeed() {
   setupMyService();

 myService.getEventsFeed(feedUrl, handleMyFeed, handleError);
 }

 function handleMyFeed(myResultsFeedRoot) {
   alert("This feed's title is: " + myResultsFeedRoot.feed.getTitle().getText());
 }

 function handleError(e) {
   alert("There was an error!");
   alert(e.cause ? e.cause.statusText : e.message);
 }

// Create the calendar service object
var calendarService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');

// The default "private/full" feed is used to insert event to the
// primary calendar of the authenticated user
var feedUri = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full';

// Create an instance of CalendarEventEntry representing the new event
var entry = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry();

// Set the title of the event
entry.setTitle(google.gdata.Text.create('JS-Client: insert event'));

// Create a When object that will be attached to the event
var when = new google.gdata.When();

// Set the start and end time of the When object
var startTime = google.gdata.DateTime.fromIso8601("2008-02-10T09:00:00.000-08:00");
var endTime = google.gdata.DateTime.fromIso8601("2008-02-10T10:00:00.000-08:00");
when.setStartTime(startTime);
when.setEndTime(endTime);

// Add the When object to the event
entry.addTime(when);

// The callback method that will be called after a successful insertion from insertEntry()
var callback = function(result) {
  PRINT('event created!');
}

// Error handler will be invoked if there is an error from insertEntry()
var handleError = function(error) {
  PRINT(error);
}

// Submit the request using the calendar service object
calendarService.insertEntry(feedUri, entry, callback, handleError, google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry);
</script>
 <form>
 <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="getMyFeed()" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the strat button i got an error:

```
google.gdata is undefined   

...Service = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1'...
```

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

wrap all your javascript code with window.onload event, 
I think it'll help you to escape from "google.gdata is undefined  " error.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call to `google.gdata` before it exists. Reading your code, it looks like you are dynamically loading the gdata library. It looks like `getMyFeed` is to be called on load. As such, don't try to access `google.gdata` until after `getMyFeed` has executed.

I would also recommend moving your inline script to your head, and specifically above the other `script` tag.